# How to add order status to commerce_line_item_table view in same way as in the commerce_user_orders view?

Tags: views, commerce

I am trying to add user's order status to commerce_line_item_table view same as it is present in commerce_user_orders view. When user click on order no in commerce_user_orders view and it goes to commerce_line_item_table view here the order status is not present i want to add order status in this view. Any Help please

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can add the `Commerce Order: Order ID` relationship to the view and then add the `Commerce Order: Order status` field and it'll provide the line item's order's status in the view.

Add the relationship:
[image: Listing the relationships on a view]
[image: Configuring the order id relationship on a view]

Then, add the field:
[image: Order status field configuration]

Now, your view will have order status on the line items:
[image: Line items with order status fields]